# How do you get the filename of a Python wheel when running setup.py?

Tags: python, cross-platform, setup.py, python-wheel

I have a build process that creates a Python wheel using the following command:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

The build process can be run on many platforms (Windows, Linux, py2, py3 etc.) and I'd like to keep the default output names (e.g. `mapscript-7.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`) to upload to PyPI.

Is there anyway to get the generated wheel's filename (e.g. `mapscript-7.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`) and save to a variable so I can then install the wheel later on in the script for testing?

Ideally the solution would be cross platform. My current approach is to try and clear the folder, list all files and select the first (and only) file in the list, however this seems a very hacky solution.

Comment: Do you need this info in the setup script (easy) or in some custom code (hard)?

Comment: The main purpose was to then be able to copy the generated file, and to install the wheel on the command line - the --find-links option resolved this without having to know the filename. I'm still interested if it could be achieved without getting list of files and parsing names

Comment: I need this so I can push the wheel file to my private package index

Comment: @cowlicks - twine can be pointed at the folder to upload the package - see current answer

Comment: @geographika I'm not using twine. I'm using a tool provided by 3rd party.

Comment: @hoefling Could you share the easy solution? I could probably work my way from there.

Comment: Are there any news about this question? I can implement one of the solutions suggested by [hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650249/hoefling) and i welcome those one, but it would be still nicer to obtain a clean futureproof solution which does not depend on internal API.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### `setuptools`

If you are using a `setup.py` script to build the wheel distribution, you can use the `bdist_wheel` command to query the wheel file name. The drawback of this method is that it uses `bdist_wheel`'s private API, so the code may break on `wheel` package update if the authors decide to change it.

```
from setuptools.dist import Distribution


def wheel_name(**kwargs):
    # create a fake distribution from arguments
    dist = Distribution(attrs=kwargs)
    # finalize bdist_wheel command
    bdist_wheel_cmd = dist.get_command_obj('bdist_wheel')
    bdist_wheel_cmd.ensure_finalized()
    # assemble wheel file name
    distname = bdist_wheel_cmd.wheel_dist_name
    tag = '-'.join(bdist_wheel_cmd.get_tag())
    return f'{distname}-{tag}.whl'
```

The `wheel_name` function accepts the same arguments you pass to the `setup()` function. Example usage:

```
>>> wheel_name(name="mydist", version="1.2.3")
mydist-1.2.3-py3-none-any.whl
>>> wheel_name(name="mydist", version="1.2.3", ext_modules=[Extension("mylib", ["mysrc.pyx", "native.c"])])
mydist-1.2.3-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Notice that the source files for native libs (`mysrc.pyx` or `native.c` in the above example) don't have to exist to assemble the wheel name. This is helpful in case the sources for the native lib don't exist yet (e.g. you are generating them later via SWIG, Cython or whatever).

This makes the `wheel_name` easily reusable in the `setup.py` script where you define the distribution metadata:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension
from setup_helpers import wheel_name

setup_kwargs = dict(
    name='mydist',
    version='1.2.3',
    packages=find_packages(),
    ext_modules=[Extension(...), ...],
    ...
)
file = wheel_name(**setup_kwargs)
...
setup(**setup_kwargs)
```

If you want to use it outside of the setup script, you have to organize the access to `setup()` args yourself (e.g. reading them from a `setup.cfg` script or whatever).

This part is loosely based on my other answer to [setuptools, know in advance the wheel filename of a native library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60643710/2650249)

#### `poetry`

Things can be simplified a lot (it's practically a one-liner) if you use `poetry` because all the relevant metadata is stored in the `pyproject.toml`. Again, this uses an undocumented API:

```
from clikit.io import NullIO

from poetry.factory import Factory
from poetry.masonry.builders.wheel import WheelBuilder
from poetry.utils.env import NullEnv


def wheel_name(rootdir='.'):
    builder = WheelBuilder(Factory().create_poetry(rootdir), NullEnv(), NullIO())
    return builder.wheel_filename
```

The `rootdir` argument is the directory containing your `pyproject.toml` script.

#### `flit`

AFAIK `flit` can't build wheels with native extensions, so it can give you only the purelib name. Nevertheless, it may be useful if your project uses `flit` for distribution building. Notice this also uses an undocumented API:

```
from flit_core.wheel import WheelBuilder
from io import BytesIO
from pathlib import Path


def wheel_name(rootdir='.'):
    config = str(Path(rootdir, 'pyproject.toml'))
    builder = WheelBuilder.from_ini_path(config, BytesIO())
    return builder.wheel_filename
```

#### Implementing your own solution

I'm not sure whether it's worth it. Still, if you want to choose this path, consider using [`packaging.tags`](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/tags/) before you find some old deprecated stuff or even decide to query the platform yourself. You will still have to fall back to private stuff to assemble the correct wheel name, though.

Answer (score 8):

My current approach to install the wheel is to point pip to the folder containing the wheel and let it search itself:

```
python -m pip install --no-index --find-links=build/dist mapscript
```

twine also can be pointed directly at a folder without needing to know the exact wheel name.

Comment: This actually does not answer the question which was about how to programatically determine the name of the output file of the setup.py script.

Comment: Technically no - which is why I accepted the other answer. However, if someone wants to know the filename to install or upload a wheel they just created then this answer could help someone. It skips having to know the filename completely.

Answer (score 5):

I used a modified version of hoefling's solution. My goal was to copy the build to a "latest" wheel file. The `setup()` function will return an object with all the info you need, so you can find out what it actually built, which seems simpler than the solution above. Assuming you have a variable `version` in use, the following will get the file name I just built and then copies it.

```
setup = setuptools.setup(
    # whatever options you currently have
    )
wheel_built = 'dist/{}-{}.whl'.format(
    setup.command_obj['bdist_wheel'].wheel_dist_name,
    '-'.join(setup.command_obj['bdist_wheel'].get_tag()))
wheel_latest = wheel_built.replace(version, 'latest')
shutil.copy(wheel_built, wheel_latest)
print('Copied {} >> {}'.format(wheel_built, wheel_latest))
```

I guess one possible drawback is you have to actually do the build to get the name, but since that was part of my workflow, I was ok with that. hoefling's solution has the benefit of letting you plan the name without doing the build, but it seems more complex.

Comment: In case you run other setup.py commands than bdist_wheel (eg clean), then command_obj will not contain a 'bdist_wheel' key and you will get an error message.