# Get the name of the file that would be generated by setup.py sdist, bdist_wheel, etc

Tags: python, setuptools

I am writing a script where I want to check for the presence of an sdist and wheel for the current version of a package, *before* generating it with Setuptools.

However, the generated wheel names tend to be somewhat complicated, and constructing them by hand isn't necessarily a good idea.

Is it possible to somehow query from Setuptools the filename (ideally the full path) that *would* be used for an sdist or wheel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939257

Comment: Thanks @sinoroc, those both appear to be duplicates of this question.